# Handling of cassandra blocking writes when exceeds the memtable_cleanup_threshold

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-streaming, cassandra-3.0

I was reading through the cassandra flushing strategies and came across following statement -

```
 If the data to be flushed exceeds the memtable_cleanup_threshold, Cassandra blocks writes until the next flush succeeds.
```

Now my query is, let say we have insane writes to cassandra about 10K records per second and application is running 24*7. What should be the settings that we should make in following parameters to avoid blocking.

```
memtable_heap_space_in_mb 
memtable_offheap_space_in_mb 
memtable_cleanup_threshold
```

& Since it is a Time Series Data , do I need to make any changes with Compaction Strategy as well. If yes, what should be best for my case.

My spark application which is taking data from kafka and continuously inserting into Cassandra gets hang after particular time and I have analysed at that moment, there are lot of pending tasks in nodetool compactionstats.

```
nodetool tablehistograms



 %       SSTables   WL             RL             P Size        Cell Count
                            (ms)           (ms)           (bytes)
50%     642.00    88.15           25109.16     310         24
75%     770.00    263.21         668489.53   535         50
95%     770.00    4055.27       668489.53   3311       310
98%     770.00    8409.01       668489.53   73457     6866
99%     770.00    12108.97     668489.53   219342   20501
Min      4.00        11.87           20924.30     150         9
Max     770.00    1996099.05 668489.53   4866323 454826


Keyspace : trackfleet_db
    Read Count: 7183347
    Read Latency: 15.153115504235004 ms
    Write Count: 2402229293
    Write Latency: 0.7495135263492935 ms
    Pending Flushes: 1
        Table: locationinfo
        SSTable count: 3307
        Space used (live): 62736956804
        Space used (total): 62736956804
        Space used by snapshots (total): 10469827269
        Off heap memory used (total): 56708763
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.38214618375483633
        Number of partitions (estimate): 493571
        Memtable cell count: 2089
        Memtable data size: 1168808
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 88033
        Local read count: 765497
        Local read latency: 162.880 ms
        Local write count: 782044138
        Local write latency: 1.859 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Percent repaired: 0.0
        Bloom filter false positives: 368
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 29158176
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 29104216
        Index summary off heap memory used: 7883835
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 19720712
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 150
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 4866323
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 7626
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 3.5
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 6
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
        Dropped Mutations: 359
```

After changing the Compaction Strategy :-

```
Keyspace : trackfleet_db
    Read Count: 8568544
    Read Latency: 15.943608060365916 ms
    Write Count: 2568676920
    Write Latency: 0.8019530641630868 ms
    Pending Flushes: 1
        Table: locationinfo
        SSTable count: 5843
        SSTables in each level: [5842/4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        Space used (live): 71317936302
        Space used (total): 71317936302
        Space used by snapshots (total): 10469827269
        Off heap memory used (total): 105205165
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.3889946058934169
        Number of partitions (estimate): 542002
        Memtable cell count: 235
        Memtable data size: 131501
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 93947
        Local read count: 768148
        Local read latency: NaN ms
        Local write count: 839003671
        Local write latency: 1.127 ms
        Pending flushes: 1
        Percent repaired: 0.0
        Bloom filter false positives: 1345
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 54904960
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 55402400
        Index summary off heap memory used: 14884149
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 34918616
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 150
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 4866323
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 4478
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Dropped Mutations: 660
```

Thanks,

Comment: can you include `nodetool tablestats` for your table?

Answer (score 1):

I would not touch the memtable settings unless its a problem. They will only really block if your writing at a rate that exceeds your disks ability to write or GCs are messing up timings. "10K records per second and application is running 24*7" -- isn't actually that much given the records are not very large in size and will not overrun writes (a decent system can do 100k-200k/s constant load). `nodetool tablestats`, `tablehistograms`, and schema can help identify if your records are too big, partitions too wide and give better indicator of what your compaction strategy should be (probably TWCS but maybe LCS if you have any reads at all and partitions span a day or so).

`pending tasks in nodetool compactionstats` has nothing to do memtable settings really either as its more that your compactions not keeping up. This can be just something like spikes as bulk jobs run, small partitions flush, or repairs stream sstables over but if it grows instead of going down you need to tune your compaction strategy. Really a lot depends on data model and stats (tablestats/tablehistograms)

Comment: Thank you Chris, I was not well since few days. my application is running as of now. will share the nodetool tablestats once it will get hang.

Comment: I have edited my with tablehistograms. Can you please check and tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: `SSTable count: 3307` is the problem. You need to use a different compaction strategy probably TimedWindowCompactionStrategy, but LeveledCompactionStrategy will also help and little easier to set. Can enable it on 1 node with JMX to test  see https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/213370546-Change-CompactionStrategy-and-sub-properties-via-JMX

Comment: `jmx_set -m org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace= trackfleet_db,columnfamily=locationinfo CompactionParametersJson \{"class":"LeveledCompactionStrategy","sstable_size_in_mb":"256"\}` and give it long time for compaction tasks to go down `nodetool compactionstats`. Although can also just skip it and alter it cluster wide right away, as it cant really be any worse than hitting >600 sstables per read

Comment: My Cassandra has heavy write work load & as per documentation "LeveledCompactionStrategy" is not good in that case. I'm inserting at around 10K records per second. What do you suggest ? shall I still go ahead with Level Compaction ? https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction

Comment: I have changed the Compaction Strategy and shared the result. Can you please check if it is making any difference now ?

Comment: 5842/4 means that it hasnt compacted yet, this might take days to catch up. is `nodetool compactionstats` making progress? LCS is almost always the right choice if you are using SSDs. STCS is only useful if you virtually never actually read your data. The overhead of the reads with STCS can generate so much IO and GC pressure that it massively trumps the IO overhead of LCS in scenarios like this. While that is a decent article it is 7 years old and times have changed a bit.

Comment: What if I'am not using SSDs as of now , Shall I go with TWCS ? What should be the time duration for compaction ?

Answer (score 0):

you may refer this link to tune above parameters. http://abiasforaction.net/apache-cassandra-memtable-flush/

> **memtable_cleanup_threshold** – A percentage of your total available memtable space that will trigger a memtable cleanup.
>   memtable_cleanup_threshold defaults to 1 / (memtable_flush_writers +
>   1). By default this is essentially 33% of your
>   memtable_heap_space_in_mb. A scheduled cleanup results in flushing of
>   the table/column family that occupies the largest portion of memtable
>   space. This keeps happening till your available memtable memory drops
>   below the cleanup threshold.

Comment: Anything that I should do for Compaction thing ?

Comment: If it is TTL based Time series data and you dont perform delete ops then you may look into TWCS as well else go ahead with STCS and tune if required.

Comment: You may go with Size Tiered Compaction Strategy (STCS) and Leveled Compaction Strategy (LCS) both while LCS has much better read characteristics than STCS. But based on your application behavior you should go. refer below https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configChooseCompactStrategy.html

Comment: @Laxmikant - no Its not TTL based. I'm constantly storing the data into tables and they are ever growing tables . What parameters should I keep in mind to tune this STCS.

Comment: @Pandey - I'm going to have insane read/ write operations but as you said LCS is better for read characteristics so should stick with STCS ?

Comment: You may go with any compaction strategy. They have some specific features so please refer https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configChooseCompactStrategy.html. This will help to you.

Comment: @Pandey - Thank you, I'll go through with the given document and will try to tune my application accordingly.